# Send different response body based on resource type in REST

Tags: java, json, rest

I have a resource which has a type in it. Based on the type it will have different configurations.

- When its of type `1`, `GET` would return parameters `{ a, b, c, $, %, &}`
- When its of type `2`, `GET` would  return parameters `{ a, b, c, -, +, =}`

The same URI is used to retrieve the resource, but with different response. Should i create a schema such that i make `{a, b, c}` objects mandatory, and `{$, %, &, -, +, = }` objects optional?

Or should i consider these type `1` and `2` as two different types of resources all together with different URI's and having different response schemas ?

Comment: 1. That is not valid JSON. 2. Where is your Java question? 3. What do you mean by 'a resource which has a type in it'?

Comment: Is this ambiguity helping the producer or consumer.